# How to add checkbox values (client ids) to a User attribute (User.clients)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've been struggling to get this to work following a tutorial. I've got Users that have profiles, and a Client model that, through a 'many to many' join table, establishes the relationships between the user and the clients.

What I'm trying to do is create a list of check boxes generated from the list of clients in the DB that you can tick on or off, and then when you submit it, the user will have the relationship to those clients through the join table.

It's sort of working with static data as you can see below:

**/profiles/show.html.erb**

```html
<% @clients.all.each do |client| %>
  <li>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[client_ids][]", client.id %>
    <%= client.client_name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Add Clients', '../assign_clients/' + @profile.user.id.to_s , class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

**Routes**

```html
get 'assign_clients/:id', to: 'users#assign_clients'
```

And finally in my **users_controller.erb**

```html
def assign_clients
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.client_ids = [1,2]
  redirect_to :back, alert: 'Assigned Users'
end
```

Obviously it's just using hard coded values of 1 and 2. What I'm not sure how to do is wrap the checkboxes in the correct form tag/simple_form (which I am using), and then with the 'submit' button, have that do the 'assign_clients' action that passes through the values.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm not sure how to do is wrap the checkboxes in the correct form
>   tag/simple_form (which I am using), and then with the 'submit' button,
>   have that do the 'assign_clients' action that passes through the
>   values.

In order to create a form that will trigger the assign_clients method a route needs to be setup in your routes.rb file like the following:

```
resources :users do
  patch 'assign_clients', to: 'users#assign_clients', as: 'assign_clients'
end
```

This sets up a route for a user that you can use the http patch method with (ie. UPDATE). The plan is to pass the client_ids to the users controller as params from the form. I gave it a path name so that we can reference it in the form as user_assign_clients_path(:user_id)

Now that we have the route set up...using the default rails form tags you can structure the form along the lines of this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_assign_clients_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <li>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[client_ids][]", client.id, @user.clients.include?(client) %>
      <%= client.client_name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Clients", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

This will create a form allowing you to post the selected clients as an array of ids to the assign_clients method.

Finally, the assign_clients method can then retrieve the client_ids from the params hash (via params[:user][:client_ids] most likely) and update the user instance (retrieved using user_id from params hash also). You will probably have to add `client_ids: []` to the end of your strong parameters list for user to whitelist it - but this essentially should behave like a typical update method.

```
def assign_clients
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @user.update(user_params)
  redirect_to wherever_path
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    client_ids: []
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write such a comprehensive reply. That's a massive help. I had gotten slightly closer since my initial post, however I was trying to use post rather than patch. This is a massive help – I've been struggling with this for literally hours!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand several basic concepts, let me explain to you:

1. `on: member` routing - in order to solve your issue directly, your route should be something like:

   ```
   resources :users do
     post '/assign_clients/:client_id', on: :member
   end
   ```

so that other than user_id, the :client_id can be also passed in as a parameter. For the details, you can read about [rails guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

2. For the checkbox way, you need `nested_attributes` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. So that you can achieve what u need with a simple `update` call on users.
3. You can also implement a customised logic, with the client_ids passed in as parameters. In order to learn how forms & parameters work in rails, you can build a form, submit it, and see how it goes in the rails server log.

If anything is unclear, simply comment below & I'll try to update.